# Tikz - Why is relative positioning not working?

Tags: tikz-pgf

MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,through,backgrounds}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
\draw[<->] (0,8.5) node[above]{P}--(0,0)--(8.5,0) node[right]{Q};
\draw[name path=D] (0,0) plot [domain=0:8] (\x,8-\x) node[above right, pos = 0.9]{D};
\draw[name path=S] (0,0) plot [domain=0:7.5] (\x,2+\x) node[right]{$S$};
\draw[name path=S1] (0,0) plot [domain=0:7.5] (\x,\x) node[right]{$S + $ sub};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Note that in the 3rd line of Tikz code, I've used pos = 0.9, which as I understand should place it 9/10 of the way along the line. Instead, I get this:

[image]

Any idea why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with Torbjørn T. and have a slightly different proposal to achieve the desired effect: `decorations.markings`, which works for general plots.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
\draw[<->] (0,8.5) node[above]{P}--(0,0)--(8.5,0) node[right]{Q};
\draw[name path=D,postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,
mark=at position 0.9 with {\node[above right] (mypos){D};}}}] (0,0) plot [domain=0:8] (\x,8-\x);
\draw[name path=S] (0,0) plot [domain=0:7.5] (\x,2+\x) node[right]{$S$};
\draw[name path=S1] (0,0) plot [domain=0:7.5] (\x,\x) node[right]{$S + $ sub};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The `pos` parameter only works some types of path construction, `plot` is not among these as far as I can see. See section 17.8 *Placing Nodes on a Line or Curve Explicitly* on page 235 of the manual for version 3.0.1.a (current stable version). After describing places where `pos` does work, there is a sentence on the following page saying

> For all other path construction operations, *the position placement does not work*, currently.

But for this simple case at least, figuring out proper coordinates is easy enough, so you can use

```
\draw[name path=D] (0,8) -- (8,0) node[above right, pos = 0.9]{D};
```

instead.

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,through,backgrounds}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
\draw[<->] (0,8.5) node[above]{P}--(0,0)--(8.5,0) node[right]{Q};
\draw[name path=D] (0,8) -- (8,0) node[above right, pos = 0.9]{D};
\draw[name path=S] (0,0) plot [domain=0:7.5,samples=2] (\x,2+\x) node[right]{$S$};
\draw[name path=S1] (0,0) plot [domain=0:7.5,samples=2] (\x,\x) node[right]{$S + $ sub};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - I accepted marmot's answer because it allows me to do relative positioning without declaring/knowing the coordinates, which is what I was after. However, I upvoted your answer as I found the explanation very helpful!